SQL query to select data between two dates not returning any record
I am trying to get the records of the transaction between two different dates for example
sales record for the period of 2024-07-01 to 2024-08-20 from javafx date picker using the following query
SELECT * FROM customerreceipt WHERE date Between '2024-08-01 00:00' AND '2024-08-20 00:00';

So when ever the query is executed it will return no records and when ever i parse the date
sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

It will throw and exception

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2024-07-29"

SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
                
Date date3 = sdf1.parse(fromDatePicker.getValue().toString());
//                sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
String dateStr1 = sdf1.format(date3);

//                String dateStr2 = toDatePicker.getValue().toString();
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date4 = sdf2.parse(toDatePicker.getValue().toString());
//                sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
String dateStr2 = sdf2.format(date4);


You might have 2 problems. Maybe try to solve the query issue first using mysql db tools to query the DB directly with literal date values.

SELECT * FROM houseofdates.customerreceipt WHERE date Between '2024-08-01 00:00' AND '2024-08-20 00:00';   This is the query i used in MYSQL and it returned values as expected but not on the program

Your format string requires a time after the date, but the datepicker just returns a date. Get rid of HH:mm:ss from the format string.

Alright thanks, I did as you said and it returned nothing, empty records

Use DATE_FORMAT() function to filter data value of format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.
Where

%Y: Year (4 digits)
%m: Month (2 digits)
%d: Day of the month (2 digits)
%H: Hour (00-23)
%i: Minutes (00-59)
%s: Seconds (00-59)

For example: I'm using customerreceipt in the db<>fiddler example where  transaction_time is your datetime column of customerreceipt table. Then you may use such query as follows:
Date & Time(HH:MM:SS) filter
select * from customerreceipt  
where DATE_FORMAT(transaction_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') 
  between '2021-01-12 05:49:02' and '2021-01-18 00:06:01'
order by DATE_FORMAT(transaction_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') desc;

Date & Time(HH:MM) filter
select * from customerreceipt  
where DATE_FORMAT(transaction_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') 
  between '2021-01-12 05:49' and '2021-01-18 00:06'
order by DATE_FORMAT(transaction_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') desc;

Date only filter
select * from customerreceipt  
where DATE_FORMAT(transaction_time, '%Y-%m-%d') 
  between '2021-01-12' and '2021-01-18'
order by DATE_FORMAT(transaction_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') desc;

Sample query: db<>fiddler
Check query and see difference of output

Hi, I don't know how to thank you for the response, I really appreciate. I don't think is from the SQL query because i tried all these on MYSQL and i get all the result but on my NETBEANS code i'm still getting the java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2024-08-22" from the date picker in javafx
